# Change Backcolor of progressbar in wp8

Tags: c#, windows-phone-8

How should i change background color of progressbar control in a wp8 app. Although it can be changed via designer view , but i want to change it later via c# code which i am unable to do :( .
I tried doing

```
percentprogress.Background=<different values>
```

where different values were hex and rgb codes and percentprogress is its name and even tried

```
System.Windows.Media.Brush
```

Any idea , how to achive this?

And another thing , how to change this color everytime the user opens up the app , be it a new session or just a resume of suspended app. Should i put it under InitializeComponent(); { means below it under public MainPage() method? }

Thanks :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can change the ProgressBar color like this:

```
percentprogress.Foreground = new SolidColorBrush(Color.FromArgb(255, 24, 50, 60));
percentprogress.Foreground = new SolidColorBrush(Colors.Orange);
```

To change the code every time user opens the app - in App.xaml.cs save some static flag in Application_Launching and Application_Activated method that the color should be changed

```
public static bool ChangeColor;
private void Application_Launching(object sender, LaunchingEventArgs e)
{
    ChangeColor = true;
}

private void Application_Activated(object sender, ActivatedEventArgs e)
{
    ChangeColor = true;
}
```

and change it then in your page like this:

```
protected override void OnNavigatedTo(NavigationEventArgs e)
{
    base.OnNavigatedTo(e);

    if (App.ChangeColor)
    {
        Random m = new Random();
        percentprogress.Foreground = new SolidColorBrush(
            Color.FromArgb(255, (byte)m.Next(0, 255), (byte)m.Next(0, 255), (byte)m.Next(0, 255)));
        App.ChangeColor = false;
    }
}
```

Comment: Worked like charm , another thing , can u just help me , why do we require 'new' keyword in front of SolidColorBrush. Thanks again :)

Comment: Because you are creating new instance of Brush. You can create several Brush instances and save them locally in your app without the need for creating them again.